# Delete row if both cells contain the same root URL

Tags: excel

I have a two column spreadsheet.

In Column A I have one URL in Column B I have another URL.

I want to delete the entire row if both cells in the same row contain the same root domain.

Example:

**Delete the following**

```
Cell A1 = www.google.com 
Cell B1 = www.google.com/randomsubpage/anothersubpage
```

**Keep the following**

```
Cell A1 = www.yahoo.com/randomsubpage/anothersubpage
Cell B1 = www.google.com/randomsubpage/anothersubpage
```

Is this possible? If it's possible outside of Excel, I'm also open to suggestions.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Do they have a prefix like http:// ? Do you want to delete them completely or is it enough to flag them up so you can filter them?

Comment: Flagging them up is enough, the prefix is both http:// and https://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Place this formula in cell C1

   `=IF(LEFT(A1,FIND(".com",A1)+3)=LEFT(B1,FIND(".com",B1)+3),"Delete","")`
2. Drag down the length of your data set.
3. Filter on Column C for Delete
4. Delete the filtered rows.

This assumes all your urls are ".com". If you have ".net" or ".gov" or whatever, as well, you'll need to find a more common string to lookup in the `FIND` function and adjust the positioning accordingly.

This formula will work for multiple url endings:

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,FIND(".",A1,FIND(".",A1)+1)+3)=LEFT(B1,FIND(".",B1,FIND(".",B1)+1)+3),"DELETE","")
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this and am getting #NAME?

Please see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IP7tfdy-YXwsv7O04oWuL8C-dvolEhNHZHiPcebh1WI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: are you using `googledocs spreadsheet` or 'excel`? They are two **different** applications.

Comment: Excel, Google Docs is created so I can share an example.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post. I thought I fixed it. Replace the `Null` with `""`.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks! Have accepted as the answer, I can't upvote due to my low rep.

Comment: I came up with an alternative one at more or less the same time, will post it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should try and make it cope with http:// or https:// and possibly subdomains and domains like .tv but maybe I'm over-thinking it! Not sure whether www should be considered part of the URL, but haven't put that in at present:-

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://",""),"https://","")&"/",FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"http://",""),"https://","")&"/"))
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"http://",""),"https://","")&"/",FIND("/",SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B1,"http://",""),"https://","")&"/"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Tom, I can't upvote as I only have 13 rep and need 15. So here's one for you - +1

Comment: Thanks for the thought :-)